# Adding two lists to Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, xml

I have a navigation drawer thats added like this:

```
    DrawerLayout myDrawLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    newList = new ArrayList<String>();
    newList.add("Test1");
            newList.add("Test2:);
    viewLists = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer_2);
    viewLists.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_left, newList));
```

And I have my xml main.xml defined as follows.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
class="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout 
 android:id="@+id/myBack"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/find"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Search" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/find"
        android:hint="Type a location or an address"
        android:inputType="text" />
 </RelativeLayout>
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />


 </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_Linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_2"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

As mentioned in another StackOverflow thread, I grouped the two ListViews into a LinearLayout because DrawerLayout But the second ListView is not being populated.

If someone can tell me what I am doing wrong I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your first list view `@+id/left_drawer` height is match_parent. Please make it to wrap_content and check.